# Do I need to download Qiskit from IBM Quantum Experience?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Do I need to download Qiskit separately or can I learn and write programs as well as practically view possible visualizations in IBM Quantum Experience itself?

Answer (score 4):

You can use so-called Quantum Lab in IBM Q Experience web interface. Log into your account on IBM Q and click on this icon:

[image: Quantum Lab]

After that, click on New notebook button  and here you can write your code in Qiskit and run it.

[image: Quantum Lab 2]

The Quantum Lab is based on Jupyter notebooks and interactive Python.

Also, you can use the Qiskit tutorial which is a part of the Quantum Lab.

Comment: thanx .... i am new to this field as was getting confused with using both q experience and qiskit. ur ans helped

Comment: @parth: IBM Q Experience is a platform providing quantum resources (i.e. quantum processor). Qiskit is a programming language (or one of extension of Python, to be precise) for programming quantum processors. You can use either graphical composer on IBM Q Experience website or Qiskit at the website or Qiskit as desktop application. If my answer is OK for you, may I ask you to accept it (a tick under voting buttons)?

Comment: @parth, by accepting the answer you respect the time and effort that people put to answer your questions, in addition, "you" "help" others who have the same question to follow the most helpful solution among all answers.